# Android -There are black horns in bitmap by use drawRoundRect

Tags: bitmap

> I used the below to make a  bitmap with rounded border,  But, there are black 
>   horns! How do I remove it? Who can help me?

```
my code:

  public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap1(Bitmap bitmap, int color, int cornerDips, int borderDips, int size) {


        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth()+2*borderDips,
                bitmap.getHeight()+2*borderDips,
                Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        final RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, output.getWidth(), output.getHeight());
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        // prepare canvas for transfer
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth((float) borderDips);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, borderDips, borderDips, paint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, borderDips, borderDips, null);

        return output;
    }
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hquDw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I changed `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` to `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`,  and then the problem solved !